# My table headers are split between two lines of text and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright so I'm trying to make my first website, I have a table that pops up when my website switches to a certain hash. When this table pops up however the headers are forced onto two different lines of text so instead of looking like `Forward-Tilt`
it looks like `Forward` then on a separate line it says `tilt`.
So far I've tried changing the margin and the padding but I can't get the text to show all on one line.

```
#damagetablemario {
   display:none;
   width:80%;
   position:relative;
   top:300px;
   left:200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
 }

th {
   padding:30px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}


<table id = "damagetablemario">
   <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th>Forward  Tilt</th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">10%</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Back-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Air"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

At the moment its looking like https://gyazo.com/ea7ca8c3070d6f1a426c71272be9b386
but I want it to all be on one line like https://gyazo.com/f8f2a14b0464b1ab6f98d41e3e995abb this one.

Comment: add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force your headings to stay on one line, you can use the `white-space: nowrap;` css [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and value.

Here is your example with this property.

```css
#damagetablemario {
   width:80%;
   position:relative;
   top:300px;
   left:200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
 }

th {
   padding:30px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id = "damagetablemario">
   <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th>Forward  Tilt</th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">10%</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Back-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Air"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you set `display` to `none` for your table which may you want to display it by code any ways if you want to set title text in one line of text you should use `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;` like below:
[white-space: nowrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) and [overflow: hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for your `th`.

```css
#damagetablemario { 
   width:80%;
   position:relative;
   top:300px;
   left:200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
 }

th {
   padding:30px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
td {
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id = "damagetablemario">
   <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th>Forward  Tilt</th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">10%</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt">sd</td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt">sd</td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt">vv</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash">sd</td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash">sd</td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash">sd</td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air">sd</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air">sd</td>
      <td class = "Back-Air">sd</td>
      <td class = "Up-Air">sd</td>
      <td class = "Down-Air">sd</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#damagetablemario {
   width:80%;
   position:relative;
   top:300px;
   left:200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   white-space:nowrap;
 }

th {
   padding:30px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
   padding:30px;
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id = "damagetablemario">
   <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th><span>Forward  Tilt</span></th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">10%</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash"></td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Back-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Up-Air"></td>
      <td class = "Down-Air"></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you wanna replace all ur '-' bw th elements with whitespace?

Comment: Sorry, your answer is also correct, because you used `white-space:nowrap;` in `#damagetablemario`.